# "Keep iTune music files organized" no longer works?

Tags: itunes

I remember iTunes used to have the option to "keep music files organized" (i know it still does in its advanced Properties). When I used to edit music's artist, genre or album information. The mp3 file is automatically updated as well. But lately I've been updating some  mp3s. And if I tried to open the updated mp3's Properties, under Details, the Artist, genre, and album information is not available. How can i fix this?

**Added:** you can try editing [this](http://www.filedropper.com/undiscloseddesires-muse) mp3 file with iTunes, it didn't work on my PC

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bm6z.jpg) of what Im seeing after the edit.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I was modifying iTunes stuff just fine last night.  Are you sure your files weren't flagged as read-only or something?

Comment: @Zoredache This link has a screenshot of what I'm seeing (http://i.stack.imgur.com/1bm6z.jpg) you can try downloading the mp3  (http://www.filedropper.com/undiscloseddesires-muse) and try editing with your iTunes(no virus), it didn't work on my pc =(

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me sometimes and I mostly find that it is because the tune you are editing is playing or it is open in another application.

If this is not the case then I can only assume it is because of iTunes 11. There has been a few bugs found so far.

However this has happened to be before with iTunes 10. I just ignored it and it seemed to fix itself. How about restarting your computer or reinstalling iTunes to see if anything changes?

EDIT- Also I don't think "Keep Music Files Organised" applies to ID3 tags. I think it just puts the music into folders based on Album and Artist. Tags should always update.